# Customization of MyApps Microsoft

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to customize my site: http://myapps.microsoft.com .
I have been reading and I read that the only customization ables to do, is change icon. More than that I read that I could edit , color, background and icon in the login page of MyApps.
Someone know, If can I customization, more things for the MyApps Page? I would like to change the background, the font, and move the icons.

Thx.